Looking for a specific source in Kierkegaard
In his book "Irrational Man", William Barrett starts Chapter 1 with:

"The story is told by Kierkegaard of the absent-minded man so abstracted from his own life that he hardly knows he exists until, one fine morning, he wakes up to find himself dead."

The quote is all over the Internet but I cannot find a source in the book itself (available in the public domain): telling me which story.
Given that Kierkegaard wrote a lot, I would not know where to start to look for the  original quote, assuming that Barret did not make  this up. (I read German, if that is any help.)   If anyone can point me in the right direction, then I would appreciate it.

It seems that Barrett is the source of the many web references and unfortunately he does not give references.
The statement is a paraphrase and thus it is hard to find, particularly on English translations available.
Having said that, I've found it into Concluding Unscientific Postscript to Philosophical Fragments (1846), English translation: Cambridge UP, 2009, page 140:

the uncertainty of death is just a something in general, then my own dying is itself only a something in general. Perhaps dying is also a something in general for systematicians, for distracted people. For the late Bookseller Soldin dying is said to have been such a something in general: ‘When he was about to get up in the morning he was not aware that he was dead.’ But for me, my dying is not at all a something in general; maybe for others my dying is a something in general.

Note: the bookseller Soldin is a recurring character in K's scripts.
It is also worth noting that on the following page Barrett quotes Socrates' "Know thyself!"
But there is also another famous Socrates' dictum: "The unexamined life is not worth living (Apology, 38a5)" and it is well-known Kierkegaard's concern with Socrates, since the dissertation On the Concept of Irony with Continual Reference to Socrates (1841).

Was the "something in general" some sort of fixed Danish expression for a certain philosophical concept, in the same way "das Ding in sich" became a fixed expression for another concept in German?

@nomadreid The Postscript is a book of dichotomies, most importantly objective vs subjective truth, with the big claim that despite the best efforts of scholars, the world can't all be boiled down to objective/scientific/impersonal/outer truth.  When K says his dying isn't "something in general" this is him rebelling against that; one's dying must be must actually be something subjective/unscientific/personal/inner.  Although it is possible for scholars to study K's death as "something in general", for K it's a mistake to think the "in general" gives the entire picture.
